# I am getting error while installing truffle in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: truffle

When i enter this command:
`sudo npm install -g truffle`

I get the following error:

```
> truffle@5.0.27 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/nslabiitp/.config/truffle/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Configstore.get all [as all] (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/configstore/index.js:31:1)
    at new Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/configstore/index.js:25:31)
    at Function.Config.getUserConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-config/index.js:395:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.command.command (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/develop.js:2:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.module.exports.$schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/index.js:9:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/cli.js:33:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:65:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:71:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
Error: Error while attempting to download and cache solc 0.5.8: Command failed: node ./build/cli.bundled.js obtain --solc=0.5.8
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/nslabiitp/.config/truffle/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Configstore.get all [as all] (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/configstore/index.js:31:1)
    at new Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/configstore/index.js:25:31)
    at Function.Config.getUserConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-config/index.js:395:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.command.command (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/develop.js:2:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.module.exports.$schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/index.js:9:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/cli.js:33:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:19:1)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap fa1fcd3fc6c4fef3eaf9:65:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:71:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

    at postinstallObtain (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/scripts/postinstall.js:13:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/scripts/postinstall.js:20:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
+ truffle@5.0.27
updated 1 package in 40.63s

I am unsure of what i am doing wrong and will appreciate pointers
```

Comment: Same question for me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031399/error-eacces-permission-denied-open-root-config-truffle-config-json  do you have a broader range of steps that you have followed?

Answer (score 2):

Fix for me was upgrade to node v12.6 [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/truffle/config.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031399/error-eacces-permission-denied-open-root-config-truffle-config-json/57040836#57040836)

I did try several fixes, hence the solution above might not be your case, however it is important that you test at least with a version higher than node v10, as there have been other issues on this version mentioned in the github webpage.